# Create Pedigree Tree / Family Tree using echarts

Tags: echarts, family-tree, ngx-echarts, pedigree

I want to create the Pedigree Tree, I found couple of libraries which uses D3.js. I have listed them below

- [DTree](https://github.com/ErikGartner/dTree)
- [pedigreejs](https://ccge-boadicea.github.io/pedigreejs/)

As we are already using echarts for other graphs and charts, I don't want to use D3.JS for now. Is there any library or solution to create the same.

I have created the Pegigree tree using Graph Nodes, but I am looking for better solution.

[image]
[image]
[image]